# PHP IF OR statement validation error

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using the below code in order to add all Wordpress posts (excluding the 'sliders' category) to a category called 'Frontpage' ID = 28

```
function add_category_automatically1($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
$postsWeWants = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_author FROM $wpdb->posts where ID = $post_ID");
foreach ($postsWeWants as $postsWeWant) {
    if (!in_category('sliders'))  {
        $cat = array(28, );
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);
    }
}
```

I want to add the exception of an additional category called 'business-information' but I can't get the OR operator to validate properly.

I was looking at using something like below

```
function add_category_automatically1($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
$postsWeWants = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_author FROM $wpdb->posts where ID = $post_ID");
foreach ($postsWeWants as $postsWeWant) {
    if (!in_category('sliders')) OR (!in_category('business-information')) {
        $cat = array(28, );
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the possible problem with parenthesis, if you are using `!`, shouldn't it be `and`? `NOT sliders`  `&&`  `NOT business-information`...

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong instead `if (!in_category('sliders')) OR (!in_category('business-information')) {`

write it like this (one more thing which is mentioned by @FirstOne you need to use `AND` instead `OR` to apply both conditions not one of them)

```
if( !in_category('sliders')  AND !in_category('business-information') ) {
...
}
```

so that both `!in_category` checks will be in same `if( ... )` scops

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if (!in_category('sliders')) OR (!in_category('business-information'))
//                         ^ -- ^ -- and here
```

is wrong. Because you close `)` and open `(` too early.
Proper code is:

```
if (!in_category('sliders') OR !in_category('business-information'))
```

And by the way such logic is **invalid**. If item is in `'business-information'` then `!in_category('sliders')` **true**. I suppose you need to check for not existing in both cats:

```
if (!in_category('sliders') AND !in_category('business-information'))
```